# Using Jabba (java) in macos

Tags: java

I recently started using [jabba](https://github.com/shyiko/jabba) and I installed a couple of java versions

```
$ jabba ls
adopt@1.13.0-0
openjdk@1.13.0
zulu@1.13.0
```

and setup

```
$ java --version
openjdk 13 2019-09-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu13.27+9-CA (build 13+33)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu13.27+9-CA (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)

$ javac --version
javac 13
```

But I am not able to open Dbeaver, when I try I get this prompt

[image]

Comment: Have you posed this question to the developer?  They would be better suited to address the problem related to their software.

Comment: What is your JAVA_HOME environment variable set to?

Comment: @abc thank you for your reply. Because I need it urgently. I removed jabba and installed the one from the oracle site. But I think it was empty.